# autoresizingMask for fixed margin sizes

Tags: iphone, ipad, layout, uiview, autoresizingmask

In a view containing several subviews, one of the subviews should remain a fixed, non-zero distance from the top and bottom of the superview. In these images, this view is shown in gray:

[image: Portait]

[image: Landscape]

According to the documentation, this view should have a mask of `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`. However, this causes the view to expand its height to take over the entire superview. How can the view be contained to fixed, but non-zero margins? Thanks.

Comment: quick question, does the width resizing work?

Comment: Yes. Only the height is problematic.

Comment: What's the autoresizing mask set to on the superview? Also, are you setting the mask in IB or in code?

Answer (score 2):

`UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` should work.

However, there's a bug with UIView auto-sizing when the parent view's height/width become small (and everything breaks when it becomes zero) — it might just be that UIView height/width can't go negative.

I've come across this problem when doing initWithFrame:CGRectZero; it might also happen if you use something like `subview.frame = self.bounds` when self.bounds is CGRectZero (or otherwise small).

My bruteforce debugging method would be to override setFrame: and setBounds: to add an NSLog.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Oddly, if I create a category with setBounds on UIView, and call super, I get, "-[UIView setBounds:]: unrecognized selector". Any idea why that would be?

Comment: Because a category is not a subclass. Boy, that was dense.

Comment: For "base-calling" in a category, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487828/if-i-override-a-class-method-is-there-a-way-i-can-call-the-original-method-the/3490215#3490215